# FCP issue: longer than 3s (desktop)

Tags: google-search-console, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I am facing speed issue in google search console

[image]

Although my site speed is considered good as shown from multiple speed tools

**Google Lighthouse**

[image]

**Gtmetrix**

[image]

I have requested to validate this issue and after 10 days I got the same issue?

> **FCP issue: longer than 3s (desktop)**

Could you please guide me

- **why I got this issue although my site speed looks good and**
- **how can I solve this issue in google search console?**

Comment: Have a look at the waterfall (or is it yslow?) in gmetrix, that will likely show you what is taking the time.

Comment: Thanks @Steve for your quick response, google ads take some time and unfortunately I can't control this! so I think  91% and 94% are a good values with a site has ads, so what do you think?

Comment: Google Lighthouse says "First Meaningful Paint" at 0.7 seconds, so search console saying first content paint more than 3 seconds doesn't make a lot of sense.   I suspect it is a problem with how it is measured in this case.

Comment: I have not put a lot of confidence in GSC's speed page.  It's experimental and in the past has been unreliable IMO.  Even today, it's "temporarily disabled due to upcoming changes in the report".

Comment: Could anyone add his answer with some guidelines to improve speed to give him the bounty before it expired?